# Creating a plot to show if values match

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
structure(list(date1_sched = structure(c(16415, 16407, 16407, 
16415, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16453, 16453, 16454, 16486, 
16486, 16502, 16492, 16492, 16543, 16543, 16543, 16506), class = "Date"), 
    DiaryDate_Act = structure(c(16415, 16418, 16415, 16418, 16411, 
    16413, 16407, 16410, 16407, 16410, 16407, 16411, 16407, 16411, 
    16415, 16417, 16415, 16417, 16418, 16419), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The 2 columns are filled in with dates such as:

```
id  date1_sched DiaryDate_Act

1 2014-12-11 2014-12-11
2 2014-12-03 2014-12-14
3 2014-12-03 2014-12-11
4 2014-12-11 2014-12-14
5 2015-01-10 2014-12-07
```

I tried to plot the ids that match the 2 dates. In other words on the x I tried to have  `DiaryDate_Act`, y  `date1_sched` and the intersection of x with y to show the id, however I can not set it for matching dates.

[image]

Comment: For me it is not clear how your plot should look like, could you provide an example?

Comment: *however I can not set the time.* What do you mean by that? If you have that many points. I would just use `geom_point` and color and if you really need to see the ids I would use `plotly` to hoover over the points and see the additional info.

Comment: @ M-M time means dates, I dont know how to show the ids of the matching dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update for OP's follow up question:*** [How to show just the id's that match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012122/creating-a-plot-to-show-if-values-match/56012431?noredirect=1#comment98669836_56012431)

If you want to have `label` only for matching dates, then following works:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Matching_id = replace(rownames(df), 
                       which(date1_sched!=DiaryDate_Act), NA)) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=DiaryDate_Act, y=date1_sched)) +
             geom_label(aes(x=DiaryDate_Act, y=date1_sched, 
                        label=Matching_id, color= (date1_sched==DiaryDate_Act))) + 
             guides(color=FALSE)
```

<sub>You can ignore `geom_point` to just have those with matching dates and don't illustrate the others  at all.</sub>

[image]

***First version:***

There is no need to append new column to your dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df) + 
 geom_label(aes(x=DiaryDate_Act, y=date1_sched, 
                label=rownames(df), color= (date1_sched==DiaryDate_Act))) + 
  labs(color="Matching Dates")
```

<sub>`color` is showing if the dates in two columns are the same.</sub>

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time and help. One more question please how to show just the id's that match?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
ggplot(df) + geom_label(aes(x = DiaryDate_Act, y = date1_sched, label = id))
```

[image]